# How to filter rows that has multiple condition MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, where-clause, having-clause

I have a table that contains my product details

```
+-----+------------+--------+-------+---------+
| id  | product_id | cat_id | field | value   |
+-----+------------+--------+-------+---------+
| 166 |        121 |     12 | model | Core i7 |
| 164 |        121 |     12 | brand | Intel   |
| 172 |         15 |     12 | model | Core i5 |
| 170 |         15 |     12 | brand | Intel   |
+-----+------------+--------+-------+---------+
4 rows in set
```

Now I want to write a query that gives me product_id(s) with this conditions:

1. Brand = Intel
2. model = Core i7

I've tried this one but it didn't returns any rows, I guess I should use JOIN.

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_product_details_fields` 
WHERE `field` = 'brand' AND `value` = 'Intel' AND `field` = 'model' AND `value` = 'Core i7'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `group by` and `having`:

```
select product_id
from wp_product_details_fields
where field in ('model', 'brand')
group by product_id
having max(field = 'model' and value = 'Core i7') = 1
   and max(field = 'brand' and value = 'Intel'  ) = 1
```

Or better yet, using tuple equality:

```
select product_id
from wp_product_details_fields
where (field, model) in ( ('model', 'Core i7'), ('brand', 'Intel') )
group by product_id
having count(*) = 2
```

Comment: Nice job on the tuple syntax +1.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen But note (with disappointment) that (in MySQL at least) the tuple method cannot use an index (at least as far as I'm aware)

Comment: @Strawberry That's good to know, learning tons of things here today `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

Use `OR`

You should try like below:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_product_details_fields` 
WHERE (`field` = 'brand' AND `value` = 'Intel') OR (`field` = 'model' AND `value` = 'Core i7')
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to rethink your database structure, i would suggest you to have field for model and field for brand. so you can do simple 'select' query. And filter the rows.

Comment: I think this is more of a comment than an answer